# How to resolve the memory error in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython

I have 2gb of csv files to be loaded into python and then concatenate them

After the concat it is throwing a memory error 
Can anyone help me on how to solve this issue because I have to use this dataframe quiet often

Comment: use pyspark to load the data. To install pyspark `pip install pyspark`

Comment: Thanks for replying

Comment: If u dont mind is there way to read with pandas as I am new to python

Comment: increasing RAM of your machine might help.

Comment: My machine has 16gb of RAM

Answer (score 0):

sorry l can't respond in the comment section yet, but to read from a csv using pandas

`import pandas as pd
csv_data = pd.read_csv("csv_name.csv")`

Comment: I have used this but that doesnt work for larger datasets

Answer (score 0):

`import csv
reader = csv.reader(open('csv_name.csv'))`


`def gen_chunks(reader, chunksize=100):
    """ 
    Chunk generator. Take a CSV reader and yield
    chunksize sized slices. 
    """
    chunk = []
    for i, line in enumerate(reader):
        if (i % chunksize == 0 and i > 0):
            yield chunk
            del chunk[:]
        chunk.append(line)
    yield chunk`


`for chunk in gen_chunks(reader):
    print (chunk) # process chunk`

`# test gen_chunk on some dummy sequence:
for chunk in gen_chunks(range(10), chunksize=3):
    print (chunk) # process chunk`

Comment: faced a similar problem and found an alternative solution, you can use the library "dask"  e.g

Answer (score 0):

faced a similar problem and found an alternative solution, you can use the library "dask" 
 e.g:

```
# Dataframes implement the Pandas API
import dask.dataframe as dd`<br>
df = dd.read_csv('s3://.../2018-*-*.csv')
```